# Is there a way to change the font style of the "References" section?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, bibliographies, capitalization, sectsty

Is there a way to change the font style of the "References" section of a document?

I'm using the `sectsty` package to modify section fonts and my code does not seem to affect the "References" section of my document.

Are there any other packages, tips, or tricks I can use to change this?

Below is the code I'm using. Thanks!

```
% I want to produce "REFERENCES", not "References"
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\uppercase}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! I added some other tags that may be relevant to your question. (This also provided the opportunity to create a {sectsty} tag.)

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I tried to add other (existing) tags and it said I couldn't add non-existing tags (but they were existing). Regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\MakeUppercase{References}}
```

Replace `\refname` by `\bibname` if your class is `book`.

If you are using `biblatex`, the relevant commands are described in section 3.5.7 of the manual (see `texdoc biblatex`).

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This may have adverse effects e.g. in the table of contents.

Comment: @lockstep Ah, yes I was thinking of that side-effect but didn't test it. Thanks for pointing that. (and +1 to your answer)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding formatting macros to the definition of `\refname` (which will produce adverse effects in other places, e.g. in the table of contents), use `\MakeUppercase` in the definition of `\allsectionsfont`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Including the references in the table of contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize\MakeUppercase}

% Would also affect ToC entry
% \renewcommand{\refname}{\MakeUppercase{References}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{foo}

Some text.

% Reference section without BibTeX
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```